# MySQL joining 2 queries without matches

Tags: php, mysql

my database exist of 2 different tables called

```
Wardrobe_CloakTable & Wardrobe_ServiceTable
```

they both have some different values but im trying to collect the SUM of each hours 'price' column.

This query gives me the right result for just Wardrobe_CloakTable

```
SELECT DATE(delivered) as date, sum(price) as sum, HOUR(delivered) AS hour
          FROM Wardrobe_CloakTable
         WHERE payingcustomerID = '$payingcustomerID'
           AND delivered >= CONCAT(CURDATE() , ' 07:00:00')
           AND delivered <  CONCAT(CURDATE() , ' 07:00:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         GROUP BY DATE(delivered), HOUR(delivered)
```

This gives me something like

```
---------------------------------
|    date    |  sum  | hour     |
| 2016-09-15 |  100  |  9       |
| 2016-09-15 |  200  |  10      |
| 2016-09-15 |  100  |  12      |
| 2016-09-15 |  100  |  18      |
---------------------------------
```

So only the hours where there is actually data, what i would like to do is have an output like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    date    |  sum(CloakTable)  | sum(ServiceTable) | hour     |
| 2016-09-15 |  100              |  200              |  9       |
| 2016-09-15 |  200              |  500              |  10      |
| 2016-09-15 |                   |  400              |  11      |
| 2016-09-15 |  200              |                   |  14      |
| 2016-09-15 |  100              |  400              |  15      |
| 2016-09-15 |  100              |  200              |  18      |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So far i have tried to create is with a UNION and a FULL JOIN, but as i noticed a full join is not possible in MySQL. Unless you do LEFT then RIGHT.

The closest i have come to something usefull is:

```
SELECT  DATE(delivered) as date, 
    sum(price) as sum,
    HOUR(delivered) as hour

          FROM Wardrobe_CloakTable  
          WHERE payingcustomerID = 2
           AND Wardrobe_CloakTable.delivered >= CONCAT(CURDATE() , ' 07:00:00')
           AND Wardrobe_CloakTable.delivered <  CONCAT(CURDATE() , ' 07:00:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
           GROUP BY DATE(delivered), HOUR(delivered)
    UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE(time) as date,
    sum(price) as sum,
    HOUR(time) as hour
    FROM Wardrobe_ServiceTable           
         WHERE payingcustomerID = 2
         AND Wardrobe_ServiceTable.time >= CONCAT(CURDATE() , ' 07:00:00')
         AND Wardrobe_ServiceTable.time <  CONCAT(CURDATE() , ' 07:00:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         GROUP BY DATE(time), HOUR(time)
```

This gives me:

```
---------------------------------
|    date    |  sum  | hour     |
| 2016-09-15 |  100  |  9       | (Cloaktable)
| 2016-09-15 |  200  |  10      | (Cloaktable)
| 2016-09-15 |  100  |  9       | (service)
| 2016-09-15 |  100  |  11      | (service)
---------------------------------
```

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `Wardrobe_CloakTable` (
  `ID` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `payingcustomerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deviceID` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `terminalnumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qrcode` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `cloakroomsection` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cloakroomnumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isbag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `delivered` datetime NOT NULL,
  `collected` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `reservedtime` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `Wardrobe_ServiceTable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payingcustomerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qrcode` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: i think you can / want to join them by the condition `ON Wardrobe_CloakTable.date = Wardrobe_ServiceTable.date AND Wardrobe_CloakTable.hour = Wardrobe_ServiceTable.hour`.

Comment: Can you add your datatables schema?

Comment: if i knew how to easily get that in phpmyadmin ? can you help there?

Comment: Click on your table in the left menu, then "Export" in the top one: set custom export by getting structure only

Comment: Tried to add it, hope its the correct one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonny,

I got a working request. Not 100% sure it is the best way to handle it, but at least it's working:

```
SELECT date_buy, hour_buy, sum(sum_cloak) AS `sum(CloakTable)`, sum(sum_service) AS `sum(ServiceTable)` FROM (
    SELECT DATE(wct.delivered) as date_buy, HOUR(wct.delivered) AS hour_buy, sum(wct.price) AS sum_cloak, 0 as sum_service FROM Wardrobe_CloakTable wct
    WHERE wct.payingcustomerID = 2 
        AND wct.delivered >= CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 07:00:00')
        AND wct.delivered < CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 07:00:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    GROUP BY date_buy, hour_buy

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATE(wst.time) as date_buy, HOUR(wst.time) AS hour_buy, 0 AS sum_cloak, sum(wst.price) as sum_service
    FROM Wardrobe_ServiceTable wst
    WHERE wst.payingcustomerID = 2
        AND wst.time >= CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 07:00:00')
        AND wst.time < CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 07:00:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    GROUP BY date_buy, hour_buy
) fullTab
GROUP BY date_buy, hour_buy
```

Comment: It is actually working! the 2nd statement should be wst.time instead of wst.delivered but else its giving me exactly the result i want. Will stick with this as i have used enough time on already.. BUT THX!

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the different column names as I made my test columns before your export! I made the edit